# Recursively replace certain text in all files following certain pattern with another text

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I have a certain files contained in different directories inside a certain parent directory. Some of these files are prefixed with certain text. I want to replace this text with another text using powershell. I have tried below. But no luck. The powershell outputs as if the file names have been renamed. However when I checked back in the directory it was not actually reflected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `ForEach-Object` loop just takes the name of the files, replaces the prefix, then echoes the modified string. Use [`Rename-Item`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849763.aspx) instead of `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem abc* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('abc', 'uvw') }
```

Comment: Not working recursively to rename files inside subdirectories

Comment: added `-Recurse` after `Get-ChildItem`, seems working. Am I write with this?